# Multiple RSS link tags within the head, valid markup or not?

Tags: html, rss, html-head

Is it valid to include multiple RSS feeds within the `<head>` tag?

What I mean is, tags as follow:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="feed one" href="/rss/feedone"/>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="feed two" href="/rss/feedtwo"/>

..... etc
```

We have a small collection (five total) of RSS feeds that we have had for a while, but have only ever included the 'main' one in within the head tags.

Is it okay to include all of them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that's totally valid, and the browser should offer the choice of which feed to subscribe to (those that still support rss, anyway)

Comment: tested in firefox 5 and chrome rss extension, you are correct. a list of available rss feeds is presented. awesome, thanks!