# 2 RSS feed links in header?

Tags: rss

I know its possible to put an RSS feed link in the header of a page so it shows as a button in the address bar. Im assuming the answer is no, but is it possible to have 2 links?

If so, how widely supported is this?
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292244/multiple-rss-link-tags-within-head-tag-valid

Comment: Your right. Should I delete this question?

Comment: If you wanted the question to stick around as a word variant stub, you can flag to close as duplicate or wait for other users to do so. Or you could just delete if you didn't want it around before someone posts the same answer. Up to you really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is yes:
[Multiple RSS link tags within the head, valid markup or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292244/multiple-rss-link-tags-within-the-head-valid-markup-or-not)

Thanks to random for answering this, im just posting here so I can mark this answer as correct.